# How to handle the infrared divergence of massless $\phi^4$ in scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, regularization

[image]

For massless $\phi^4$ theory, if exterior momentums are going to zero, then this diagram will be

$$\int \frac{dk^4}{k^4}$$ 
will suffer from  infrared divergence.
Because the infrared divergence, unlike UV divergence, often has physical meaning, how do I handle this divergence? What's the meaning?

Comment: Check this out: [http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1375](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1375). It's a nice introduction. Your problem is discussed.

Comment: Adding to the article that Steven pointed out. Within dimensional regularization scheme IR divergences are automatically taken into account. You can check that explicitly by dim. reg. computation. Also see Amit's book: http://www.amazon.com/Field-Theory-Renormalization-Critical-Phenomena/dp/9812561196

IR divergences, if unavoidable, usually means the point about which perturbation theory is constructed is an inappropriate one.

Comment: related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122620/