# Massless $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, field-theory, renormalization

Most of the standard textbooks on QFT discuss in some detail the massive $\phi^4$ theory in 4d space-time.

> I would be interested to see a discussion of **massless** $\phi^4$ theory (in fact other non-vanishing renormalizable interactions would be of interest too). Particularly I am curious in the following two questions:
>
> 1) how to compute the S-matrix in low order of perturbation (taking into account both UV and IR divergences).
>
> 2) if the physical mass vanishes, does the bare mass vanish?

UPDATE: Essentially the same question was asked more than 4 years ago here: 
[Massless $\lambda \phi^4$ QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122620/massless-lambda-phi4-qft?rq=1)
However it is still unanswered.

Comment: If you know a reason why this would not just be the limit of massive $\phi^4$ theory for $m\to 0$, it would be nice to mention that since that would dissolve the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The reason is that the relevant expressions for S-matrix diverge in that limit. They should diverge because the IR divergences should be taken into account like in QED.

Comment: It might also be relevant to mention that [$\phi^4$ theory is known to be trivial in >4d](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Triviality_of_four_dimensional_phi%5E4_theory_on_the_lattice), making perturbative computations inherently questionable.